# Why document.evaluate returns correct value after highlighting web elements manually but fails to return when executed first at browser console?

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath, dom-events, document.evaluate

Requirement to retrieve the web-elements name via xpath on a fully loaded webpage.

So I'm using document.evaluate and below is the line of code which I execute from chrome browser console

**Attempt 1:**

```
document.evaluate('//*[contains(@class,"column-title")]//*[contains(text(),"Cut")]', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.innerHTML;
```

**Output:** In browser console as below:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Can't read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML')
    at <anonymous>:1:169
```

**Attempt 2:** I goto elements tab, highlight the web element with help of highlighter and switch to console tab and execute same line of code

**Output:** **It returns the innerHTML element name successfully i.e., cut in this example.**

How to make this line of code execute successfully when executed directly from browsers console tab first?

Comment: Since we have no idea what the document is, we cannot directly answer the question; but it is obvious that your XPath returns no matches. Is it possible your document changes in the meantime? Anyway, do a bisection debug, by trying simpler XPath expressions and observing what they match, and drill down to see what part of it fails to match; the immediately-simpler XPath evaluation (the most complex successful one) will probably give hints as to what went wrong.

Comment: Thank you Amadan but the xpath here returns and highlights exact match on the web page when evaluated from browsers elements tab.

Comment: I know. I read your question. But we cannot reproduce that, so you have to do some debugging to find the exact condition under which the match fails. Presumably `'//*'` does not fail. Does `'//*[contains(@class,"column-title")]'` fail? etc.

Comment: OK. It fails at '//*[contains(@class,"column-title")]' with null. But when we highlight the element in 'Elements' tab with same xpath and come back to console tab and try, it returns correct value.